# How do i only add necessary files and folders to GitHub if i want to add a project to my repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

So my question is basically how i can push projects from VS22 or VS Code to github with only the neccessary stuff. I pushed a project to github and it had files which my C Drive location where i stored the project on my pc for example. Im new to this so please keep that in mind when answering.

I tried to upload a Project to Github
I excepted it to only upload the neccessary files like https://github.com/Januadrym/NoteAppCommandLine for example.

It resulted in the mess displayed in the picture [Github Imagine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14Lo.png)

Comment: read up on `.gitignore`

Comment: Note you don't upload or push "files"; instead you push "commits". (With the word "commit" being a noun here.). So, the answer is to only "stage" and "commit" the files that you wish to push. (With "commit" being a verb here.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a place where all your folders can sort of gather into one spot for a singular push:

You can create a new folder on your desktop (lets call it mainproject just for example sake) and then run git init to turn that folder into a repository.

Now you can drag in all the folders that you want included into that repository or just copy them in.  Kind of like a mothership loading all the smaller ships onto it (the smaller ships being your projects).

Each project should have its own folder within the the mainproject folder.

It could look something like:

```
mainproject
    -project_a
    -project_b
    -project_c
```

That way everything is nicely tucked into it.  Then what you do is connect this repository (the one you initialized in mainproject) to your remote github.  From there you can push it with something like

git push -u origin whateveryourmainbranchis

the origin here just refers to the name of your remote and the latter part is just the name of the branch that you want pushed to it.

(assuming you've stage and commit all the changes before pushing to your remote)

git add . (This will stage all your changes)
git commit -am "Some version and Some note"  (This will commit to your local repository of git and allow you to add a message)

Also if you want to exclude files @rioV8 is correct.  You can use .gitignore (you have to create a file and name it .gitignore making sure it literally is named .gitignore and not .gitignore.txt)

In there you can list extensions that you want to have excluded.  Some people exclude .env files to keep there private passwords out of a push.  Some people exclude cache files.  There's a whole syntax for it out there.

Hope this helps!